# Verifying form input stops for few seconds using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently trying to input a specific value for different input fields (username, name, password and confirm password). And after it has input the values, it'll click on the submit button, and return any  validationMessage error. However, for the password confirmation text input it shows that it has an error even though all other text input passes.

The code:

```
try:

element = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
element.send_keys(random_value)
if WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username[name='username']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage") !="":
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username[name='username']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage"))
else:
    print("Username: PASS")
  
except:
    print("Check username html value")

try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_name("name")
    element.send_keys(random_value)
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#name[name='name']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage") !="":
        print(WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#name[name='name']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage"))
    else:
        print("Name: PASS")  

    
except:
    print("Check name html value")


try:
    element2 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    element2.send_keys(random_value)
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password[name='password']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage") !="":
        print(WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password[name='password']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage"))
    else:
        print("Password: PASS")
    
except:
    print("Check password html value")

try:
    element3 = driver.find_element_by_name("password_confirmation")
    element3.send_keys(random_value)
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password_confirmation[name='password_confirmation']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage") !="":
        print(WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password_confirmation[name='password_confirmation']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage"))
    else:
        print("Password confirmation: PASS")
    
except:
    print("Check password confirm html value")
```

Currently the error i'm getting is that the output is "Check password confirm html value", but the driver.find_element_by_name("password_confirmation") is correct and it does input the string specified

Comment: Use `except Exception as e: print(e)` to print out the error that occurred in your try block.

Comment: I get this as the output, just lots of white lines, 'Message:(white lines)                    '

Comment: What error do you get if you run the code without the try/except clause?

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: So it times out when trying to find the password confirmation. Try increasing the timeout of 1 to 10. If that doesn't work, double check the html source code. Also, it is not necessary to induce webdriverwait after you've already assigned element3 to the password_confirmation element. The same applies for all of your try/except blocks.

Comment: https://imgur.com/swyBiiS this is html source code for the password confirmation. I tried to increase the timeout to 10, but still its showing the same timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your css selector is wrong. You are using `input#`, which will search for an `id`. The `id` in your html is not `pass_confirmation`, but `password_confirm`.

Try this.

```
try:
    element3 = driver.find_element_by_name("password_confirmation")
    element3.send_keys(random_value)
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password_confirm[name='password_confirmation']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage") !="":
        print(WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password_confirm[name='password_confirmation']"))).get_attribute("validationMessage"))
    else:
        print("Password confirmation: PASS")
    
except:
    print("Check password confirm html value")
```